# Error accessing Azure Service Bus from Storm cluster

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are trying to read messages from Azure Service Bus (ASB) through Apache Storm cluster using a custom built spout java code. When the storm topology is submitted to run in cluster mode, we are facing the following issues:

- Service or property not registered:  com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract class com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
- Unable to add Azure Service Bus Connector
- Setup of Services Failed.
- Async loop died!

When the same topology is submitted in local mode (without cluster), the same code works fine and able to receive messages from ASB.

Did anyone face similar issue when accessing ASB from java environment and able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

See the workaround on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/466. There are problems with shaded jars, you only need to include a new transformer in the pom.xml to solve the issue. It worked for me.

Comment: I was unable to fix it using this plugin :( As today, the only workaround I have is to merge manually the generated "com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.Builder$Exports"

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a **jar-with-dependencies** of a custom azure-service-bus client and in my case (Carlos/Robert)/[issue#466](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/466) workaround (maven-shade-plugin) doesn't work.

I always get the same error :

```
Service or property not registered: com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract class com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
```

NB: I just found another open ticket that is maybe related to the same issue here : [issue#465](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/465)

Root cause of this error is the following wrong resource :

```
META-INF/services/com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.Builder$Exports
```

Both `azure-core` and `azure-servicebus` (0.8.3) dependencies use the same file (same name and same location) which embed "package to export" list. **This 2 files should be merged**.

My sad workaround is to use 2 executions of the maven-assembly:

- step A) first execution makes a dependencies directory,
- step B) second execution append my version of the fixed `Builder$Exports` resource, remove MS signed files(security issue), and make a final jar file.

This solution is not yet acceptable because the fixed resource is not picked from azure dependencies. I had my own extra resource. But today I have no other workaround.

The fixed MS merge result file (src/main/resources) is:

file name

```
META-INF/services/com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.Builder$Exports
```

file content

```
com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.Exports
com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.Exports
com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.pipeline.apache.Exports
com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.pipeline.jersey.Exports
com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.utils.Exports
com.microsoft.windowsazure.credentials.Exports
com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.configuration.Exports
```

pom plugin definitions:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>dir-jar-with-dependencies</id><!-- step A -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/assembly/dir_jardeps.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <finalName>busclient</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar-with-dependencies-ms-patch</id><!-- step B -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/assembly/jardeps_mspatch.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <finalName>busclient</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

file `src/assembly/dir_jardeps.xml` :

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>dir-jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

file `src/assembly/dir_jardeps.xml` :

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>dir-jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF</directory>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/busclient</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
             <exclude>META-INF/services/com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.Builder$Exports</exclude>
             <!-- MS jars are signed : remove signatures -->
             <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
             <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
             <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: That is what the shaded jar plugin should be doing. The good thing to note is that very soon, we will not need to do such things. A new version of the Java SDK will be coming out soon and will not have the service loader issues.

Comment: Thanks @Justice for the information. Do you know when the release will be done (any date/link?)?

Comment: They should start hitting the repo's in Nov. The work on the generator is being done in http://github.com/azure/autorest.

Comment: Maven shade 2.4.2 release note extract: "* [MSHADE-190] - Shade does not relocate the contents of META-INF/services files" so I will try this new version

Comment: this new version doesn't work too ; so will keep my own workaround while waiting for next MS version... thanks @Justice

Answer (score 0):

In the gradle build script I have added this plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

Instead of jar task I used shadowJar task where I gave archive name and main class. The method mergeServiceFiles() merges the duplicate service file names.

```
shadowJar {
archiveName = "sample.jar"
manifest {
attributes 'Main-Class': ' com.test.asset.Test'
}
mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

I hope this helps some one

Thanks,
Veeresh